# Racadm commands don't work from pipeline. Inside container there is no problem with running it

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I would like to run a pipeline with some racadm commands.

- racadm -r .... remoteimage -d
- racadm -r .... set iDRAC.VirtualMedia.BootOnce 1
  etc.

I have installed racadm in the docker container. Later I have created an image from the container and I have pushed it to registry. I have tried to launch the commands from dsl and scripted piepeline. It didn't work. When connect to the container manually there is no problem with running racadm commands. I have tried to run the commands in pipeline using  shell, script.

When used shell"" - the pipeline passed but there was no result.
Have you any idea how the problem can be solved?

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your DSL? What do you mean by "didn't work" did you get an error or something else? If you got an error, what is the error message?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env groovy
node("node-01"){  shell("racadm -r .... -u .... -p .... remoteimage -d")   }                                There was no error:  Finished: SUCCESS                                                                               but the image hasn't been removed in iDRAC. Running the same command manually from container has removed the image.